# Add months to date column in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, presto

I have a date column in `my_table` and I would like to add three months to it. The [AWS Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ADD_MONTHS.html) suggests using `DATEADD` or `ADD_MONTHS`, but I'm getting the following error messages.

With `DATEADD`:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:13: Column 'month' cannot be resolved

With `ADD_MONTHS`:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:5: Function add_months not registered

This is what my data looks like:

```sql
select
    my_date
from
    my_table
limit 3
```

| my_date |
| --- |
| 2019-03-01 |
| 2019-04-01 |
| 2019-05-01 |

I would like to do the following:

```sql
select
    add_months(my_date, 3) as plus3m
from
    my_table
limit 3
```

| plus3m |
| --- |
| 2019-06-01 |
| 2019-07-01 |
| 2019-08-01 |

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Athena and Redshift are different products. You can find the link to SQL reference in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ddl-sql-reference.html.

You will need to use `date_add('month', 3, my_date)` in Athena.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! This is very confusing because googling anything related to Athena takes you to the Redshift docs, so I assumed they used the same language even though they are different products.

Comment: @ArturoSbr personally I found very useful presto [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) when working with Athena SQL, though not everything worked for me).